# Only clang-cl is supported on Windows, when I compile my webrtc server

Tags: c++, visual-studio, clang, webrtc, chromium

I'm actually trying to build my server for webrtc in visual studio 2019 with added additional directories chromium source, I'm getting this error.

```
Error C1189 #error: "Only clang-cl is supported on Windows, see https://crbug.com/988071"   Server  D:\projects\chromium-src\src\base\compiler_specific.h   13
```

Can anyone please tell me what I'm missing for a successful build.

**Edit 1:**
Now I'm sure that my compiling environment is the issue as its taking MSVC and not clang. Can anyone guide me on how to change MSVC to clang on Visual Studio.  I did try a lot but was not able to come up with a solution.

**Edit 2:**
Chromium is building with is_clang=true successfully, but its that when I use it in my webrtc-media-server where its giving the same clang error when I actually include chromium as an dependency.

Comment: Chromium uses `clang` for compiling files. Did you install depot_tools and follow the other steps for compiling it? AFAIK, they have dropped support for Microsoft's C++ compiler.

Comment: I had followed the installation steps first extracted the bundle and later gave gclient command and set the path of depot_tools in environment variable. Is there anything I have missed?

Comment: @Asesh my brother, if you know the steps to build chromium correctly in windows with clang for webrtc please can u give some time to guide me out.

Comment: If you can provide more information including the compile-time log then it would be more helpful. I don't see `compiler_specific.h` file in Chromium code base.

Comment: Just went through this code: https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/59791810ce07582736abeee287b7219be8833e00/base/compiler_specific.h which is emitting that error message. It's quite clear that your environment is configured to MSVC compiler rather than clang, that's why you are seeing that message

Comment: Sorry for the delay and thanks for making such an effort. Yes this is where I'm actuall getting the error.Can you tell me how can I configure my environment to the same.

Comment: Try compiling after running this command in command line: `set DEPOT_TOOLS_WIN_TOOLCHAIN=0` if it still doesn't work then either depot tools is not installed properly or the env. variables aren't setup properly

Comment: @Asesh I checked the depot tools are installed and the environment variable are set correctly.

Answer (score 2):

As Asesh has mentioned, the support for Visual C++ compiler has been removed. In that case, while building Chromium modify the build flags by following the steps mentioned below:

Run the following command, which will open `args.gn` file in an editor:

```
gn args out\Default
```

Specify `is_clang` boolean value to `true` in that file and save it:

```
is_clang=true
```

Answer (score 1):

I was able to come up with a hack to solve this by defining the `__clang__` in preprocessor defntions of the project properties->configuration properties->C/C++ properties->Preprocessor Defnitions.

Answer (score -1):

PowerShell script and step by step instruction here [RainwayApp / webrtc-build-scripts](https://github.com/RainwayApp/webrtc-build-scripts#build-details) will help you to build WebRTC on Windows (and patch in the case of need).

You basically need to have depot tools ready, then [build.ps1](https://github.com/RainwayApp/webrtc-build-scripts/blob/master/build.ps1) will do the rest and build the code (builds static libraries in this script, however the script itself is relatively small so it is easy to see how to adjust it further).