# Only clang-cl is supported on Windows when building project with webrtc

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++, webrtc

I am trying to build a project that contains webrtc. However compilation fails with this error :
`vendor\webrtc\src\base/compiler_specific.h(11,1): fatal error C1189: #error:  "Only clang-cl is supported on Windows, see https://crbug.com/988071"`. I have tried defining `__clang__` preprocessor definition, but this simply causes an error :
`STL1000: Unexpected compiler version, expected Clang 11 or newer.` I am using cmake with Visual Studio 2019 generator. I have installed clang-cl , both independently and as part as Visual Studio Build Tools and I have tried overwriting the path to the clang-cl executable. I am aware this is a duplicate of [Only clang-cl is supported on Windows, when I compile my webrtc server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60370428/only-clang-cl-is-supported-on-windows-when-i-compile-my-webrtc-server), but there was no conclusive answer on that issue. Am i missing something obvious? Thanks in advance

Comment: If you're set on trying to fool your build tools (not necessarily a good idea, though), then maybe *also* `#define _MSC_VER` (alongside `__clang__`). That may pass *those* tests for clang-cl but will likely cause other problems further down the build chain.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @AdrianMole I am not quite trying to fool my build tools. If there is a proper way to do this, I would like to make use of it.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out I have to specify the toolset in CMake with the -T option :
`cmake -G "Visual Studio 2019" -T ClangCl ...`